# How to heal Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

After fighting through my first few battles in the classic Pokemon Red, my Charmander has low health. How can I heal him back to full health?

Comment: -7 for a legit question, this place has grown quite awful

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer Legitimacy has absolutely zero relevance when it comes to voting.  All that matters is how useful it is.  For this question, it requires not only completely ignoring everything you're told, but also making zero effort to look online, for games that have been out for 20 years.  That's **exactly** what downvotes are for.

Comment: @Frank the game doesn't tell you anything about how to heal your pokemon, searching for it online gets you pages of results that have nothing do with the question (just try "heal charmander pokemon red" in google) and the age of the game means nothing to usefulness

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer Any amount of effort *at all* would answer this.  A search for "heal pokemon pallet town" gives a large list, all of which is helpful.  The age of a game means the chances of your answer being online much higher.  At 20 years old, there's going to be very little whatsoever that can't be found with a simple google search.

Comment: @Frank sure, a 20 minute discussion about usefulness of a question based on rules not described in "how to ask a question" is clearly a better use of time than simply answering, please add 'age of game' into How to guide

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer **First** page when you ask a question: "Provide details. Share your research."  We indicate very strongly that effort is required here.  That's how SE has *always* been.  Beyond that, complaining about enforcing our quality standards is a common theme.  We're not a forum.  We work differently, and it behooves users to try to learn how that is.  If you don't, this happens.  That's not being awful.  That's enforcing quality.  If you don't like it, take it up on Meta.

Comment: @Frank AKA use gamefaqs

Comment: I am grateful that this question is here.  This is now the top result on Google for the question "heal pokemon red" and quickly and nicely answers the question.  I had **zero** other results on the first page of Google that answered this correctly.  If a question isn't already answered on SE, it should be - other sites are a mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to hoof it all the way to Viridian to use the Pokemon center, just go home and talk to your mom. She'll suggest you take a rest, and heal your Pokemon.

Comment: Thought this was pokemon-go and you were actually suggesting that he does it in real life ; +;